# Need helps on Next.js website deployment basic knowledge?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I've built a personal website using Next.js, and now I want to deploy it on Internet.

I followed a tutorial and it told me to create a config under `project_root/config/index.js` and the content is like:

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

export const server = dev? "http://localhost:3000": "http://<the_ip_of_my_server>"
```

The constant `server` is used in the file `project_root/pages/article/[id]/index.js`, as shown below.

```
const article = ({article}) => {

    return <>
        <Meta title={article.title} description={article.excerpt}/>
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        <p>{article.body}</p>
        <br/>
        <Link href="/">Go Back</Link>
    </>
};

export const getStaticProps = async(context) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/articles/${context.params.id}`)
    const article = await res.json()
    return {
        props: {
            article
        }
    }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async() => {
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/articles`)
    const articles = await res.json()
    const ids = articles.map(article => article.id)
    const paths = ids.map(id =>
        ({
            params: {
                id: id.toString()
            }
        })
    )

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

Say now I'm using `ssh` to connect to the server, then I run into the following errors:

- When I run `npm run build` it says:

  ```
  > Build error occurred
  FetchError: request to http://<the_ip_of_my_server>:3000/api/articles failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED <the_ip_of_my_server>:3000
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/apps/my_project/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
      at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    type: 'system',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
  }
  ```

  Since now I'm on the server, so it seems like I just have to use `export const server = "http://localhost:3000"`?
- On the other hand, the command `npm run dev`, then it works. But is this still a site run in "production"?
- As you can see above, since I used both `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`, what I want is to build (so an `project_root/out/` folder will be created) to project and serving the static files in the `out/` folder, how to achieve this? Is this a correct way to serve a static website using next.js?

This is part of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build && next export",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
```

Comment: Are you trying to request data from the same application? Like you have api route and at the same time you have page with `getStaticPaths` that requests this api? Or api if different server?

Comment: @Danila: The same. I want to move those data to the database during the way when I learn more, currently I just want to use fake data as is.

Comment: Please mark some answer as accepted if your original question is resolved, or ask additional questions if it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to fetch from the same application API route during build process because your api or server is not even running yet.

Although you can just import your api handler directly to your page code and use it inside `getStaticProps` or `getStaticPaths`. It won't go into client bundle anyway

Read the notes under [this section in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)

Comment: Can you also help me clarify some concepts about the two `get...` methods?

Comment: My current idea is that: `getStaticPaths` will create an array and each element of that array will be passed, as the params, to `getStaticProps`. Then, each `getStaticProps` corresponding to a page that will be statically generated.

Comment: Yes, `getStaticPaths` generate paths for pages to create, then `getStaticProps` get this paths, fetches needed data and generate pages themselves

Answer (score 0):

I also found myself an answer from the official [vercel/next.js dicussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14505) on GitHub, where @jamesmosier answered on on Jun 24, 2020:

> The reason it is failing is because `http://localhost:3000/api/data` is not online when you are running your build.
>
> Instead of trying to call an API route in `getStaticProps` you should just put your logic directly in the `getStaticProps` function.
>
> Or if you are just getting your data from a static file (i.e. `import { data } from '../../data'`) just import that in your `pages/sales/[category].js` page and then use it in `getStaticProps`. Next will eliminate that code from any client side bundles as long as you only use it within `getStaticProps`.
>
> ```js
> // ...all of your other imports...
> import { data } from '../../data'
>
> export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
>   return { props: { params, data } }
> }
>
> // ...your other code...
> ```